# List of arguments in only one variable in bash

Tags: rsync, arguments

There is an input argument with a list of files (files with wildcards or folders) like this one:

```bash
list="file1 dir1 **.data **.source"
```

Now each element of this list must be prefixed with `--filter=+` , turning it into a list of arguments of `rsync` command, looking something like this:

```bash
args='--filter=="+ file1" --filter="+ dir1" --filter="+ **.data" --filter="+ **.source"'
```

So, when passing *$args* to `rsync $args` it should receive each argument correctly where the space in the "+ " must be just a character of the argument and not a separator of two arguments.

How to do that in shell script (bash) using only built-in shell commands? Notice that `rsync` command must receive each argument correctly.

**ONE UNSUCCESSFUL TRY:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -f
list="file1 dir1 **.data **.source"
ct=0
arr=""
for i in $list; do
    ct=$(( ct + 1 ))
    arr[$ct]="--filter='+ $i'"
done
args=${arr[*]}

set -x
echo args:$args
rsync $args srcdir destdir
set +x
```

When it's run (supposing that the folder `srcdir` exists in the current directory), it shows:

```bash
$ ./test
+ echo args: '--filter='\''+' 'file1'\''' '--filter='\''+' 'dir1'\''' '--filter='\''+' '**.data'\''' '--filter='\''+' '**.source'\'''
args: --filter='+ file1' --filter='+ dir1' --filter='+ **.data' --filter='+ **.source'
+ rsync '--filter='\''+' 'file1'\''' '--filter='\''+' 'dir1'\''' '--filter='\''+' '**.data'\''' '--filter='\''+' '**.source'\''' a b
Unknown filter rule: `'+'
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at exclude.c(904) [client=3.1.1]
+ set +x
```

Look that although `echo` shows each argument correctly:

```bash
args: --filter='+ file1' --filter='+ dir1' --filter='+ **.data' --filter='+ **.source'
```

The `rsync` command looks like not understanding each argument correctly, as the "+" finished the argument and the space wasn't part of the argument but a separator, corrupting all arguments.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of making the list of filenames and patterns as a single string, you could make it an array to begin with:

```
list=(file1 dir1 "**.data" "**.source")
```

and then loop over the elements:

```
args=()
for item in "${list[@]}" ; do
    args+=(--filter="+ $item")
done
```

That would create arguments like `--filter=+ file1`, without any quotes inside the argument string. (You don't want the quotes to go to `rsync`. It will complain about a filter rule that has them, e.g. `rsync "--filter='+ foo'" ...`)

And when you pass the array to the command, make sure to use `"${args[@]}"` to pass the array elements as distinct strings:

```
rsync "${args[@]}" "$srcdir" "$destdir"
```

In stead of `"--filter=+ foo"`, I think you could just use `--include=foo`. That would remove one problematic space from the arguments (but would no nothing about spaces or globs in the filename patterns).

---

In your case, you used `set -f` to disable globbing, `for i in $list` should work, but since you need an array, you might as well use one to begin with.

More importantly, the assignment `args=${arr[*]}` flattens the array to a single string. Now the spaces inside the arguments and the spaces between the arguments are equal, there's just `--filter=+ file1 --filter=+ dir1 ...` and the shell has no way of telling the different kinds of whitespace apart. The unquoted expansion `$args` will split on any and all white space (which the `set -x` output shows, if you care to parse the mess of quotes.)

In effect, all gains from using an array were made moot at this assignment.