# Variable rsync filter parameters

Tags: shell, rsync, parameter

I have an issue with a variable rsync parameter.
I concat filtered expression on COMPILE_FILTERS variable.
Example :

```
COMPILE_FILTERS='--filter="- js/editor/editorjs/*"'
rsync -a $COMPILE_FILTERS \
  --filter="- *node_modules*" \
  --filter="- .git*" \
  --filter="- /**/.git*" \
  $src $dest
```

The following response are displayed.

```
Unknown filter rule: `"-'
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at exclude.c(927) 
[client=3.1.3]
```

That strange because interpreter seem to block on the hyphen.

Thanks you in advance if you have an advice.

Comment: Double quote the expansion of your variable. See [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer when you say "Double quote the expansion" that mean ```rsync -a "$COMPILE_FILTERS" ``` ? I try this but that didn't work.

Comment: I'm writing an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [List of arguments in only one variable in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432352/list-of-arguments-in-only-one-variable-in-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

1. The expansion of `$COMPILE_FILTERS` is unquoted.  This mean that its value, `--filter="- js/editor/editorjs/*"`, will be split into words on whitespace (by default).  These words are `--filter="-` and `js/editor/editorjs/*"`.  The words will then undergo filename generation (globbing), but in your case, this would only be an issue if you happened to have a file matching the pattern `js/editor/editorjs/*"` somewhere.

   The splitting into two words means that `rsync` will get *two arguments*, and it fails to properly use the first of these (this is what you error message refers to).

   You solve *this* issue by double quoting the expansion of the variable.
2. The string that you save in the variable *includes* the double quotes.  If you double quote the expansion of the variable, you are basically telling `rsync` to use the filter `"- js/editor/editorjs/*"` (with double quotes and all).  This is because you use single quotes around the string.

   You solve *this* issue by assigning the correct string to the variable:

   ```
   COMPILE_FILTERS=--filter="- js/editor/editorjs/*"
   ```

   or

   ```
   COMPILE_FILTERS='--filter=- js/editor/editorjs/*'
   ```

End result:

```sh
COMPILE_FILTERS='--filter=- js/editor/editorjs/*'
rsync -a "$COMPILE_FILTERS" \
  --filter="- *node_modules*" \
  --filter="- .git*" \
  --filter="- /**/.git*" \
  "$src" "$dest"
```

Note that I have also quoted the other variables involved in the code.

See also:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)

---

If you later decide to include further filters in your variable, make sure to switch to an array (in a shell that supports these):

```bash
filters=(
    --filter="- js/editor/editorjs/*"
    --filter="- *node_modules*"
    --filter="- .git*"
    --filter="- /**/.git*"
)

rsync --archive "${filters[@]}" "$src" "$dest"
```

In shell that don't have named array variables (`/bin/sh`, `dash`), you get to type less:

```sh
set -- \
    --filter="- js/editor/editorjs/*" \
    --filter="- *node_modules*" \
    --filter="- .git*" \
    --filter="- /**/.git*"

rsync --archive "$@" "$src" "$dest"
```

You need an array or list to properly handle the separate filter arguments.  Trying to combine the multiple filters into a single string would be doable, but way harder, as you have to handle the shell's word splitting and filename globbing properly.