# not searching, dont know how to connect find and variable

Tags: linux, bash, find, variable

dont' really know how to connect find and variable
sorry for everything being in polish

```
#!/bin/bash

KONIEC=0;

while [ $KONIEC -eq 0 ]; do

    echo "-------------------------------------------------------"
    echo "1. Nazwa pliku: $NAZWA"
    echo "2. Katalog: $KATALOG"
    echo "3. Ile dni temu dostano się ostatnio do pliku: $ILEDNI"
    echo "4. Plik ma mniej niż: $MNIEJSZYNIZ"
    echo "5. Plik ma więcej niż: $WIECEJNIZ"
    echo "6. Zawartość pliku: $ZAWARTOSC"
    echo "7. Szukaj"
    echo "8. Koniec"
    echo "-------------------------------------------------------"

    read POLECENIE

    if [ $POLECENIE -eq 1 ] ; then
        read -p "Podaj nazwe: " NAZWA

    elif [ $POLECENIE -eq 2 ] ; then
        read -p "Podaj katalog(pełna ścieżka w formacie ./KATALOG/Katalog/katalog/, wielkość liter ma znaczenie): " KATALOG

    elif [ $POLECENIE -eq 3 ] ; then
        read -p "Ile dni temu dostałeś/łaś się ostatnio do pliku(0 jeżeli dzisiaj): " ILEDNI

    elif [ $POLECENIE -eq 4 ] ; then
        read -p "Plik ma mniej niż (w MB): " MNIEJSZYNIZ

    elif [ $POLECENIE -eq 5 ] ; then
        read -p "Plik ma więcej niż (w MB): " WIECEJNIZ

    elif [ $POLECENIE -eq 6 ] ; then
        read -p "Podaj zawartość tekstową pliku (aby ta opcja działała prawidłowo w ścieżkach nie mogą wyspępować spacje): " ZAWARTOSC

    elif [ $POLECENIE -eq 7 ] ; then
        echo "Trwa wyszukiwanie..."

        if [ $NAZWA ] ; then
            BUFFER1="-iname '$NAZWA'"
        fi

        if [ $KATALOG ] && [ $NAZWA ] ; then
            BUFFER1="$KATALOG* -iname '$NAZWA'"
        elif [ $KATALOG ] ; then
            BUFFER1="$KATALOG"
        fi

        if [ $ILEDNI ] ; then
            BUFFER2="-atime $ILEDNI"
        fi

        if [ $MNIEJSZYNIZ ] ; then
            BUFFER3="-size -$MNIEJSZYNIZ"
        fi

        if [ $WIECEJNIZ ] ; then
            BUFFER4="-size +$WIECEJNIZ"
        fi

        if [ $ZAWARTOSC ] ; then
            BUFFER5="|xargs grep -l '$ZAWARTOSC'"
        fi

        MAINBUFFER="$BUFFER1 $BUFFER2 $BUFFER3 $BUFFER4"

        find $MAINBUFFER

    elif [ $POLECENIE -eq 8 ] ; then
        KONIEC=1
    else echo "brak takiego polecenia"
    fi

done
```

Comment: There are several common mistakes here; [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing them out and suggesting fixes. However, your `BUFFER` variables are more complicated; I'd recommend [using an array](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432352/list-of-arguments-in-only-one-variable-in-bash) instead.

Answer (score 3):

The `[ ]` does not allow you do things like that, either use `[[ ]]` or do it as a separate test.

```
if [ "$KATALOG" ] && [  "$NAZWA" ] ; then
```

Or

```
if [[ "$KATALOG" && "$NAZWA" ]] ; then
```

- You need to Quote-All-Your-Variables.
- One more reason not to use `[ ]` in bash.

Comment: thank you very much i corrected it but now have trouble connecting find and a variable
it just does not search for anything

Comment: Not sure what does that mean.

Comment: i mean this line in the end **find $MAINBUFFER** it should do same as**find -iname name**
when i type manually in terminal manually **find -iname name** using the same name as in this script it works but does not seem to work in script :/
it basically searches nothing

Comment: Did you tried https://shellcheck.net   since you're script is that long I suggest you ask another question and post it again, You're issue of missing something was resolved this is another issue.

Answer (score 2):

A `&&` is not valid inside `[]`. Either use a `[[...]]` or:

```
If [ "$KATALOG" ] && [  "$NAZWA" ] ; then
```

Have you tried your script in shellcheck.net already?

Note that the next line 46 should end with either a newline or a `;`.

Comment: i didnt know such a page even exists, im a newbie